# Intent filter doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, html, intentfilter

I was wondering if the host in an intentfilter is necessary. And if so, does the host need to actually exist.

This is what I've tried:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="hi10.android.be"
                android:pathPrefix="/eidsignature/"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.hi10.android.be"
                android:pathPrefix="/eidsignature/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then I put a link in my html:

```
<a href="http://hi10.android.be/eidsignature/">CLICK HERE</a>
```

Here's the thing. hi10.android.be doesn't exist. So I was wondering if this needs to be a valid host for it to activate my app. If so what host should I use, since the app is still in development and isn't hosted anywhere yet.

EDIT: this isn't working btw

Answer (score 0):

No, it need not to be a valid host for using intent filter. as long as string in intent filter for host matches string in url for host. you are good to go.